# Compute $\det(tI - M)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been struggling computing $\det|tI - M|$ .

Given $M=\
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3& 2& 4 \\
        2 & 0 & 2 \\
        4 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

It has to be $(t+1)^2(t-8)$

I managed to get $(t+1)^2$, but I unfortunately didn't get $(t-8)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\det(tI-M)=\begin{vmatrix}t-3&-2&-4\\
-2&t&-2\\
-4&-2&t-3\end{vmatrix}=t(t^2-6t+9)-32-8(t-3)-16t=$$

$$=t^3-6t^2-15t-8=(t-8)(t^2+2t+1)=\ldots$$

**Added:** Developing by the middle column:

$$\begin{vmatrix}t-3&-2&-4\\
-2&t&-2\\
-4&-2&t-3\end{vmatrix}=2\begin{vmatrix}-2&-2\\-4&t-3\end{vmatrix}+t\begin{vmatrix}t-3&-4\\-4&t-3\end{vmatrix}+2\begin{vmatrix}t-3&-4\\-2&-2\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$=2(-2t-2)+t(t^2-6t-7)+2(-2t-2)=-8(t+1)+t(t+1)(t-7)=$$

$$=(t+1)(-8+t^2-7t)=(t+1)^2(t-8)$$

Comment: Can you explain what row/columns u used to evaluate that determinant?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the determinant of a $\;3\times 3\;$ matrix by rightward and leftward diagonals? That's how I did it, and always do it, in case of $\;3\times 3\;$ matrices...

Comment: No idea what you mean. I always try to find alot of zero's, if I don't find zero's I just try to get some zero's with elementary row operations, and then compute with the row that has the most zero's.

Comment: Ilan: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).

Comment: @TedShifrin Nice, but I prefer computing with rows.

Comment: Well Ilan: many times is **way** easier, shorter and faster to do diagonals. You should do yourself a favour and try to learn that method. It is worth the time.

Comment: I know this method, I'll try it now.

Comment: @DonAntonio: "favour" are you going British? What is your favorite colour?

Comment: It is ourange and rouse, @user99680 ...;)

Comment: Thanks! I got it now @DonAntonio. You're good!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

$$\det(tI-M)=\begin{vmatrix}t-3&-2&-4\\
-2&t&-2\\
-4&-2&t-3\end{vmatrix}=(t-3)[(t(t-3)-(-2)(-2)]-(-2)[(-2)(t-3)-(-2)(-4)]+(-4)[(-2)(-2)-(t)(-4)]=(t-3)(t^2-3t-4)+2(-2t-2)-4(4+4t)=t^3-3t^2-4t-3t^2+9t+12-4t-4-16-16t$$

$$=t^3-6t^2-15t-8=(t+1)^2(t-8)$$ . Select the first entry in the first row, ignore the first row and the first column, and compute $(t-3)$ times the determinant of the remaining matrix (the one that remains after ignoring the first row and the first column ). Then do the same thing with the second entry in the top row, i.e., with $(-2)$: ignore the first row and the 2nd column and multiply $(-2)$ by the determinant of the matrix that remains after deleting the first row and the second column. Then take the third entry on the first row, delete the third column, etc.

Comment: God bless you. Thanks !

Comment: No problem, Ilan, good luck.

Comment: I still don't understand how to get from Left to Right here $$=t^3-6t^2-15t-8=(t+1)^2(t-8)$$

Comment: @Ilan: I just multiplied your answer $(t+1)^2(t-8)$ through to verify it is correct. Let me see how one can go in the opposite direction.

Comment: I just don't know how to compute $$=t^3-6t^2-15t-8$$

Comment: You mean how to find the roots? One way (most likely not the fastest) is to consider divisors of $8:\pm 4, \pm2 , \pm1 $ as (one of )the possible roots. Once you have a  root r, you can divide your polynomial by $t-r$ and get a second degree polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Up to 2 by 2 and 3 by 3, there is a recipe you can do. For 2 by 2, the polynomial is
$$  t^2 - (\operatorname{trace} M)\, t + \det M. $$

For 3 by three, there is a new ingredient, call $S_2$ the sum of the three 2 by 2 "principal minors," so 
$$ S_2 = (m_{11} m_{22} - m_{12} m_{21 }) +   (m_{11} m_{33} - m_{13} m_{31 }) +  (m_{22} m_{33} - m_{23} m_{32 }).  $$

Then the characteristic polynomial is
$$   t^3 - (\operatorname{trace} M) \, t^2 + S_2 \, t - \det M. $$

I never really thought about this much, but a student said "Why didn't you say that first?" when i told him after class, so I guess it is helpful.

I get trace $6,$ then $S_2 = -4 -7 - 4 = -15,$ then det = $8.$ So, in order $6,-15,8,$ and
$$ t^3 - 6 t^2 -15 t - 8.  $$ Let me compare with the others...

Comment: Will, my students know $S_2$ by the name of $\tt{Fred}$. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin, good name. I am always mystified when people on either site ask for the name of something. And so we have http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46216/name-of-this-convex-polyhedron  Note that I have grown to quite like Joseph.

Comment: although, i have gradually come to suspect that people are hoping to find the given concept online, and that might work with a correct name. Not quite the same when it is someone with Joseph's resources.

Comment: Will, I didn't know that you had preempted my name Fred. But I had it in print long before you did so. :P

Comment: @Ted, I bow to your priority. Do you really use the name Fred in class, or in a book you wrote perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can preform row operations take twice the middle row and subtract it from the first and last

$$\begin{vmatrix}
3-t &2&4\\2&-t&2\\
4&2&3-t\\
\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
-(t+1) &2(t+1)&0\\2&-t&2\\
0&2(t+1)&-(t+1)\\
\end{vmatrix}
=(t+1)^2\begin{vmatrix}
-1 &2&0\\2&-t&2\\
0&2&-1\\
\end{vmatrix}
=(t+1)^2\begin{vmatrix}
-1 &2&0\\
2&4-t&0\\
0&2&-1\\
\end{vmatrix}
=-(t+1)^2\begin{vmatrix}
-1 &2\\
2&4-t\\
\end{vmatrix}
=-(t+1)^2(t-8)$$